# Convert array structure

Tags: arrays, json

Hi I want to convert an array from the format

```
 tableValue= [{typeID:"1",name:"xxxxx"},
    {typeID:"1",name:"aaaaa"},
    {typeID:"1",name:"bbbbb"},
    {typeID:"2",name:"ccccc"},
    {typeID:"2",name:"ddddd"},
    {typeID:"2",name:"fffff"},
    {typeID:"3",name:"ttttt"},
    {typeID:"3",name:"yyyyy"},
    {typeID:"4",name:"zzzzz"},
    {typeID:"4",name:"hhhhh"}]
```

to the format

```
tableGroup=["fk_type1":[{typeID:"1",name:"xxxxx"},{typeID:"1",name:"aaaaa"},{typeID:"1",name:"bbbbb"}],
"fk_type2":[{typeID:"2",name:"ccccc"},{typeID:"2",name:"ddddd"},{typeID:"2",name:"fffff"}],
"fk_type3":[{typeID:"3",name:"ttttt"},{typeID:"3",name:"yyyyy"}],
"fk_type4":[{typeID:"4",name:"zzzzz"},{typeID:"4",name:"hhhhh"}]]
```

**updation**
My Component is as follows:

```
createTableValues() {
    let groups = {};
    tableValue.forEach(item => {
      if (tableGroup[item.typeID]) {
        tableGroup[item.typeID].push(item);
      } else {
        tableGroup[item.typeID] = [{ 'fk_type'+item.typeID }];
      }
    });
  }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Show us what you've done so far :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one you expect is not a valid array.

It should be like this,

```
{"fk_type1":[{typeID:"1",name:"xxxxx"},{typeID:"1",name:"aaaaa"},{typeID:"1",name:"bbbbb"}],
"fk_type2":[{typeID:"2",name:"ccccc"},{typeID:"2",name:"ddddd"},{typeID:"2",name:"fffff"}],
"fk_type3":[{typeID:"3",name:"ttttt"},{typeID:"3",name:"yyyyy"}],
"fk_type4":[{typeID:"4",name:"zzzzz"},{typeID:"4",name:"hhhhh"}]}
```

And the code is,

```js
var items = [{typeID:"1",name:"xxxxx"},
{typeID:"1",name:"aaaaa"},
{typeID:"1",name:"bbbbb"},
{typeID:"2",name:"ccccc"},
{typeID:"2",name:"ddddd"},
{typeID:"2",name:"fffff"},
{typeID:"3",name:"ttttt"},
{typeID:"3",name:"yyyyy"},
{typeID:"4",name:"zzzzz"},
{typeID:"4",name:"hhhhh"}];

var output = {};
var key = 'fk_type';

items.forEach(function(item){
  var typeID = item.typeID;
  if(!output[key + typeID]) {
    output[key + typeID] = [];
  }
  
  output[key + typeID].push(item);
});

console.log(output);
```